# Kotlin smart cast not working when wrapping null-check in a function

Tags: kotlin

I've ran into something that looks like a smart cast limitation. When I do the null-check directly in the method, the field is correctly smart-casted into the non nullable field. But once I wrap it into a function, the compiler doesn't do the smart-casting. Am I missing something, or that's not possible to do?

Here's a class definition:

```
data class Foo (val id: String?){
    fun hasId() = id != null
}
```

Now using this:

```
    val foo = Foo("1")

    if (foo.hasId()) {
        foo.id.toInt() // Compilation error because id is nullable
    }

    if (foo.id != null) {
        foo.id.toInt() // All ok
    }
```

Comment: I think it's simply not "smart" enough to do it using a function like that. Possibly because it could be more complicated in certain scenarios where you are maybe also dealing with possible subclasses of `Foo` with different implementations of the function or something

Answer (score 2):

You can use the experimental contracts API to solve this. It gives the compiler more information to infer things like smart casts.

You can implement it like this:

```kotlin
data class Foo (val id: String?) {
    
    @ExperimentalContracts
    fun hasId(): Boolean {
        contract { returns(true) implies (id != null) }
        return id != null
    }

}
```

Edit:

As @Sweeper correctly noted in a comment, this doesn't actually work here due to a constraint in the contract API that only parameters to the function can be referenced by the contract.

You could think that it would work by writing it as an extension function instead, but unfortunately that doesn't work either, because `Foo` would be the parameter, not `Foo.id`.

```kotlin
// Unfortunately doesn't work either.
@ExperimentalContracts
fun Foo.hasId(): Boolean {
    contract { returns(true) implies (id != null) }
    return id != null
}
```

So for now, the only way to make it work is to make a function on `String?` directly. Like this:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalContracts
fun String?.exists(): Boolean {
    contract { returns(true) implies (this@exists != null) }
    return this != null
}

// Used like this:
if (foo.id.exists()) {
    println(foo.id.toInt())
}
```

Comment: Can you actually use `id` like that after `implies` though? I get the error "Error in contract description: only references to parameters are allowed in contract description".

Comment: @Sweeper you are right. Also see the samples https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/samples/test/samples/contracts/contracts.kt

Comment: Thanks. I was playing around with contracts and got into the same conclusion. In the end I guess it's an overkill and makes the code less readable than directly check it in the if statement. Thanks for your help anyway